# Secure Cookies using Apache

Tags: apache, cookies

How can I make a secure cookie setting at Apache ? I have tried few commands with HttpOnly and Secure but none of them works ! The Apache is being used in the application just to proxy the requests to the backend AEM CQ server.

The apache version that I am using is 2.2.31 and I have a constraint that I cannot upgrade it to higher versions.

Could anyone please help me !!!

Thanks,
Sourav

Comment: at least post what you tried so far and where in the config did you set it (context).

Comment: I tried the below settings in httpd.conf file -                                                                        Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this https://geekflare.com/httponly-secure-cookie-apache/ ? If not please check and also have you checked is there any provision of setting cookies flag in backend server you mentioned?

Link on adobe to set cokkied flags http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion-securing-apps.html

One of thread from AEM CQ defining same problem https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1562784

Comment: The blog says we cannot use that in lower versions of apache.  "Header edit is not compatible with lower than Apache 2.2.4 version"  BUT my constraint is I cannot upgrade the apache version. I tried the settings           Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure - but no luck !! Could you please suggest some other settings that i can apply at apache end.